# C#: Remote Image size without downloading it

Tags: c#

I have an image's URL. Is it possible to find out its size(in bytes) and dimensions without downloading the complete image?

**EDIT**

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)(req.GetResponse());
System.Console.WriteLine(resp.ContentLength);
```

I have written this code. It works fine for first two time and the third time it gives `WebException` i.e. "operation timed out" irrespective of the image url. Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.

You can get its size in bytes by issuing an `HTTP HEAD` command (instead of a `GET`); this will return the HTTP headers only, omitting the contents.

The HTTP header of an image will return its size in bytes:

```
Content-length: 6372
Content-type: image/jpeg
```

but not its dimensions.

So you'll have to do an `HTTP GET`...

Comment: ok ... i have written a piece of code and when I try to run it against 3 images, first 2 always works fine but the 3rd one is giving WebException i.e operation timed out but I am able to open it in the browser. Any reason for such behavior?

Comment: @RaviGupta: That is unanswerable without looking at your code. Very probably you need to work on that code to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. If you know what kind of image it is e.g. png or jpg (you can also get this information from the MIME-type of your HTTP-connection, you can download the header only and read the image extents from there. Also see this related question:

[What is the header size of png, jpg/jpeg, bmp, gif and other common graphics format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423942/what-is-the-header-size-of-png-jpg-jpeg-bmp-gif-and-other-common-graphics-for)